# Variable argument list prints garbage

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Following function prints garbage on console. Cannot understand the issue. Below is a test code fragment.

```
void
format(
    const char* pcszFormat,
    ...
    )
{
    va_list VarArglist;

    va_start(VarArglist, pcszFormat);
    printf(pcszFormat, VarArglist);
    va_end(VarArglist);
}


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    string strTest;
    const char *pcszFormatted;

    format("%x %S", 10, "Test");

    //printf("\nFormatted string: %s", pcszFormatted);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent you code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. You should use `vprintf()` to work with `va_list`.

Also don't forget to change `%S` to `%s` in order to work with normal string or change `"Test"` to `L"Test"` in order to work with wide string, or you will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()` family again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `va_list` to `printf`. Use [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead.